# how does getdepth function work in MarchingCube algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, marching-cubes, image-science

I am trying to understand Marching Cube Algorithm, so for I think I have understood how triangles are formed and how normals are calculated in each grid. I can see there is a linked list kind of structure that links each grid to another. But when I come across GetDepth(t[m]) which passes each triangles (those triangles of each grid) (t[0],..,..)individually, it returns depth of the node.

The function,

```
float GetDepth(TRIANGLE t) {

    float z;
    z = t.p[0].z;
    z = t.p[1].z > z? t.p[1].z: z;
    z = t.p[2].z > z? t.p[2].z: z;
    return z;
}
```

It looks like its trying to find max z(is it true).
I can see that it compares  " > " and then I lost it. 
Can any one please explain what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you are unfamiliar with ? as a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a). 
The code you posted is equivalent to the following:

```
float GetDepth(TRIANGLE t) {

float z;
z = t.p[0].z;
if (t.p[1].z > z) {z = t.p[1].z;} else {z = z;}
if (t.p[2].z > z) {z = t.p[2].z;} else {z = z;}
return z;
}
```

And yes, this does find the maximum z in the p array.