# how does Insert node function of Marching Cube works?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, linked-list, marching-cubes

I am trying to understand MarchingCube algorithm:
My previous question was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996097/how-does-getdepth-function-work-in-marchingcube-algorithm). Now I am stuck in one function where the node ( which holds each grid of whole cube in linked list kind of structure) is inserted. I can understand the first few line of the code but, when I look at the code I find some part of the code redundant.

```
NODE *Insert(NODE *listset, NODE *tmpNode) {
1    NODE *temp;
2
3    if(listset == NULL) return tmpNode;
4    else {
5        tmpNode->next = listset->next;
6        listset->next = tmpNode;
7        return listset;
8    }
9    temp = listset;
10    if(temp->next == NULL) {
11       if(temp->depth > tmpNode->depth) temp->next = tmpNode;
12            else {
13                tmpNode->next = temp;
14                listset = tmpNode;
15            }
16         return listset;
17    }
18    while(temp->next != NULL) {
19        if(temp->next->depth > tmpNode->depth) temp = temp->next;
20        else {
21            tmpNode->next = temp->next;
22            temp->next = tmpNode;
23            return listset;
24        }
25     }
26     temp->next = tmpNode;
27     return listset;

}
```

In this function from 1 to 8 perfectly makes sense ( its just inserting new node to its end).
How could code ever reach after that point (I mean code from 9-27) ?? Is it even necessary??

Can anyone please explain what is going in the part 9-27.

Comment: Line 9 can never be reached. Did you copy it correctly?

Comment: I believe the best way would be to read a white paper on Marching Cubes Algorithm and try to implement it by yourself from scratch. Yes, you'll have to spend quite some time, but you'll gain valuable experience on implementing something from scratch just by reading the specification of how things should work, but without seeing any exact implementation. Furthermore, hacking on such badly designed code will damage your brain and not teach you anything. Even if you untangle this code and understand it, most likely you'll forget it in a few days because you didn't design it yourself.

Comment: @Bryan - yes it the same code, I double checked by adding printf function inside and the code never reach at that point ( but works some how)

Comment: @Haroogan what ever you said is the sad truth for lazy person ;)

Comment: There is actually not really a need for an "insert node" function in a "Marching Cubes" algorithm. Are you aware of this page: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/ ? The code on this page (scroll down) works perfectly. We have built a quite complete test suite around it, all tests pass.

Comment: I have seen that website, form there I was able to understand how triangles are formed and yes I didnt saw any talk on nodes there. So you mean, instead of creating linked list of nodes we can simply go through each grid as we fill the grid with points and values and also calculate the triangles that pass through it ??